# VSTest to NUnit Migrations results in high memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, mstest, vstest

I have a large test suite that was originally run on the VSTest library. After switching to NUnit, the entire test suite can no longer run to completion. A few of the tests will complete, but the rest will fail with an OutOfMemoryException.

The code in question runs mock database queries with different filters and checks for any issues right up to the database access. These queries are run with an "and False" condition to so no data is actually returned. There are some caches here and there, but they have been removed for the unit tests.

A Google search brings up a fewer older threads on memory issues, but nothing current. I believe there may be an issue in my code, but I am also completely confused as to why this issue only popped up after switching from VSTest.

Does anyone have any ideas for a possible cause or solution? Or some insight into the differences between VSTest and NUnit?

Comment: You will have to debug further, as the cause cannot be trivial, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/08/10/why-do-i-see-executionengineexception-stackoverflowexception-and-outofmemoryexception-on-the-heap-when-debugging-net-applications/

Comment: The test suite is definitely using too much memory. Task manager shows it using several GB before it crashes or I terminate it.